# rails fields for conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, field, fields-for

I'm displaying some contacts for a case.  the problem is I want to break them up into groups.

Clients
 ...list clients
Former Attorney
 ...list former attorney
Opposing Parties
 ...list Opposing Parties

```
    <% current_account.roles.each do |role| %>
      <%= f.fields_for :case_contacts, f.object.case_contacts.order(:role) do |builder| %>
        <% if builder.object.role == role %>
          <%= render partial: 'contact_fields', locals: { f: builder, edit: edit } %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

So this works except that it leaves empty div.fields in my html.

Is there a way to put the conditional in the fields_for statement

```
    <%= f.fields_for :case_contacts, f.object.case_contacts.order(:role), if f.object.role = role do |builder| %>
```

I know this example is wrong.

And, in all actuality, I could do without the div.fields that fields_for generates all together

Edit:
I guess I don't even need to order it if fields_for only displays fields where builder.object.role = role

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer

```
 <%= f.fields_for :case_contacts, f.object.case_contacts.where(role: role) do |builder| %>
```

Comment: FYI, this will break the `field_with_errors` wrapper for validation errors on the `case_contacts` fields.  If you don't care to style based on the `field_with_errors` wrapper then it won't hurt anything.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to wrap the fields_for block with your guard condition:

```
<% if f.object.role == role %>
  <%= f.fields_for :case_contacts, f.object.case_contacts.order(:role) do |builder| %>
    <% if builder.object.role == role %>
      <%= render partial: 'contact_fields', locals: { f: builder, edit: edit } %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: but, it's the case_contact that has a role.  Ruby doesn't iterate through the case_contacts until the fields_for, right?  am I missing something?  maybe I was confusing.

Ruby won't know what role is if it's outside the fields_for